# Add linhas selecionadas do GridControl ao ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Estou tentando adicionar os meus itens do grid ao meu ObservableCollection mas estou sem sucesso.
Eu tenho uma coluna que tem o CheckBox que coloquei através da propriedade `ShowCheckBoxSelectorColumn`.

Eu tenho o seguinte Xaml:

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" AutoGenerateColumns="None"
                     FontWeight="Normal" SelectionMode="MultipleRow" Margin="0,0,0,324" SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView x:Name="view" ShowGroupPanel="True" AllowEditing="False" ShowTotalSummary="False" AutoWidth="True" NavigationStyle="Row"
                           ShowSearchPanelMode="Never" UseLightweightTemplates="All" FontSize="11" ShowCheckBoxSelectorColumn="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Codigo" Header="Código" Width="25"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Descricao" Header="Descrição"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

    </dxg:GridControl>
```

O problema é que não sei adicionar esses meus itens selecionados a uma coleção.
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto fica um pouco mais complicado porque tá usando DevExpress os controles não são igual os controles de XAML normal. Mas olhando a documentação parece que tem uma propriedade chamado "SelectedItems" no GridControl. Então num evento (como SelectionChanged por exemplo) você pode pegar os itens selecionados no propriedade "SelectedItems" e adicionar no coleção por se mesmo. Não vai ter nada simples que faz isto automaticamente. Tipo, algo assim:

```
public void grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, GridSelectionChangedEventArgs args) 
{
    collection.Clear(); // <-- Seu ObservableCollection
    foreach (var item in grid.SelectedItems) // SelectedItems vem do GridControl (eu acho)
    {
        // Depois de Clear(), adicionar os que são selecionados atualmente
        collection.Add(item); 
    }
}
```

Documentação: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridGridControltopic

Comment: Perfeito Samuel, deu certo. Muito obrigado!